# pandas DataFrame and pandas.groupby to calculate Salaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipython

For my assignment, I need to import baseball salary data into a pandas `DataFrame`.
From there, one of my objectives is to get the salaries of all the teams per year.

I was successful however in order to move onto the next task, I need a pandas `DataFrame`. `sumofSalaries.dtype` is returning `int64`.

Questions:
    1. How do I convert the data in the code following into a DataFrame?
    2. How do I delete the indexes in `sumofSalaries`?

Code:

```
 import pandas as pd
 salariesData = pd.read_csv('Salaries.csv')

 #sum salaries by year and team
 sumOfSalaries = salariesData.groupby(by=['yearID','teamID'])['salary'].sum()

 del sumOfSalaries.index.names #line giving me errors

 #create DataFrame from grouped data 
 df = pd.DataFrame(sumOfSalaries, columns = ['yearID', 'teamID', 'salary'])
 df

 _____________________________________________________________________________

 sumofSalaries:
 yearID  teamID
 1985    ATL        14807000
         BAL        11560712
         BOS        10897560
         CAL        14427894
         CHA         9846178

 ...and so on
 _____________________________________________________________________________

  df:

            yearID  teamID  salary
 yearID teamID          
 1985   ATL NaN NaN 14807000
        BAL NaN NaN 11560712
        BOS NaN NaN 10897560
        CAL NaN NaN 14427894
```

Comment: Why are you trying to delete the index?   In other words, what are you trying to get in that intermediate step?

Comment: Could you add the snippet of `Salaries.csv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need only add parameter `as_index=False` to [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), output is `DataFrame` without `MultiIndex`:

```
sumOfSalaries = salariesData.groupby(by=['yearID','teamID'], as_index=False)['salary'].sum()
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

salariesData = pd.DataFrame({
'yearID': {0: 1985, 1: 1985, 2: 1985, 3: 1985, 4: 1985, 5: 1986, 6: 1986, 7: 1986, 8: 1987, 9: 1987}, 
'teamID': {0: 'ATL', 1: 'ATL', 2: 'ATL', 3: 'CAL', 4: 'CAL', 5: 'CAL', 6: 'CAL', 7: 'BOS', 8: 'BOS', 9: 'BOS'}, 
'salary': {0: 10, 1: 20, 2: 30, 3: 40, 4: 50, 5: 10, 6: 20, 7: 30, 8: 40, 9: 50}
},
columns = ['yearID','teamID','salary']
)

print (salariesData)
   yearID teamID  salary
0    1985    ATL      10
1    1985    ATL      20
2    1985    ATL      30
3    1985    CAL      40
4    1985    CAL      50
5    1986    CAL      10
6    1986    CAL      20
7    1986    BOS      30
8    1987    BOS      40
9    1987    BOS      50

sumOfSalaries = salariesData.groupby(by=['yearID','teamID'], as_index=False)['salary'].sum()

print (sumOfSalaries)
   yearID teamID  salary
0    1985    ATL      60
1    1985    CAL      90
2    1986    BOS      30
3    1986    CAL      30
4    1987    BOS      90
```

Also if need remove index names, use assign to `(None, None)`, but if use solution above, it is not necessary:

```
sumOfSalaries.index.names = (None, None)
```

Sample:

```
sumOfSalaries = salariesData.groupby(by=['yearID','teamID'])['salary'].sum()
sumOfSalaries.index.names = (None, None)

print (sumOfSalaries)

1985  ATL    60
      CAL    90
1986  BOS    30
      CAL    30
1987  BOS    90
Name: salary, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

`del` has a [very specific meaning](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#del) in python and has no use on a dataframe like that.

You want to use `reset_index` to get rid of the `MultiIndex` after a groupby -- if you want to get rid of the `MultiIndex`, that is.

```
import pandas as pd
salariesData = pd.read_csv('Salaries.csv')

#sum salaries by year and team
sumOfSalaries = (pd.DataFrame(
                 salariesData.groupby(by=['yearID','teamID'])['salary'].sum()
                 .reset_index()
               ))
```

Read up on the [groupby docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) and the [multiindexing docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) for more information.